# Creating Netezza table from csv file with header

Tags: netezza

I need to create table in Netezza from csv file with header. Target table should have the columns as the headers in source file. Target table should have flexible structure changing based on source file headers. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your expectations are for this? You will need datatypes as well as column names, and short of using NVARCHAR(100) for everything and crossing your fingers, I don't know how to address that from the csv file alone...

If you can get your source system to provide another csv file with metadata for COLNAME,DATATYPE(Precision) you can certainly change that to a valid 'create table' statement in netezza, and then something like this to get you the rest of the way:

`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE demo_ext SAMEAS emp USING (dataobject 
('/tmp/demo.out') DELIMITER '|');`

More info here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.load.doc/c_load_create_external_tbl_expls.html

Answer (score 0):

From the question, im assuming the requirement is you need to create a new table/alter every time based on ur source csv file. Is it?
@Moutusi Das

As mentioned by Lars G Olsen, the option will be having a separate file for table creation which contains column names & datatypes. You can use unix script to get the details of table creation file & create/altee table in netezza.
Then load the table using external table command.

Comment: I do not have an option to get separate file with metadata. The input file itself will have header which should be the column name in target table and datatype for all the columns in target table will be VARCHAR. The problem is my input file structure is not consistent.